# MVC4, The controller is called from referenced assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two projects - `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`.
Both `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` are normal MVC4 applications.

In `ProjectB` I have added reference to `ProjectA` to be able to re-use some models and operations.
`ProjectA` is on local dev server url `http://localhost:1234/ProjectA/`
`ProjectB` is on local dev server url `http://localhost:5678/ProjectB/`

Everything works fine, but when I try to call `http://localhost:5678/ProjectB/Test/Act` 
the `Act` action of `Test` controller is called BUT! this controller comes from `ProjectA`!!!

Why does my `ProjectB` resolves and calls controller from `ProjectA`?
I wish to avoid this, I dont't need this behavior.
In `ProjectB` I just want to be able to call controllers from `ProjectB` 
and disable those from referenced `ProjectA`.

**Edit:**
In ProjectB I have registered only this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                namespaces: new[] { "ProjectB.Controllers" }
            );
```

But the application is still able to resolve to ProjectA controllers!?

Comment: There are two sites here (they are both running on different ports), are they separate applications in IIS or do you have one app? Are they two different solutions?

Comment: Different applications, different projects in same solution, two different instances of the ASP.Net development server, not nested in any way...

Comment: It seems that by default mvc is using all classes that are inherited from Controller, does not matter if they come from application assembly or some other assembly.

Comment: Shouldn't do - the requests against project A should only hit the routing strategy on the site that hosts the project. Had a thought though, have you checked your project B to see if there is a project A dll somewhere inside it? If the assembly is in the bin folder of project B it will be picked up by .NET and will start handling requests for that project. I've had this before where I changed the name of a project and the application was doing some strange routing afterwards - it turned out to be the old dll was still present in the bin directory along side the renamed build

Comment: Of course that there is ProjectA.dll inside ProjectB bin folder and must be there. ProjectB uses some functionality from ProjectA but I do not want to target it's controllers.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - it sounds like your ProjectB is somehow getting registering routes from ProjectA. Have you tried debugging the route registration code in both assemblies when you run ProjectB?

Comment: Only ProjectB executes routes registration.
It seems that this behavior is by design:
http://www.treeloop.com/blog/controller-type-resolution-in-asp-net-mvc
In short, MVC scans all loaded assemblies when searching for controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use namespaces for that. If you want `Project B` to call only Project B controllers, add a namespace:

`using Project B.Models.<Insert Object Here>`

This will only call Project B controllers. If you want project A, just change the namespace to projEct A.